# problem with Bounding Box GetFeature WFS

Tags: wfs, getfeature

I have a WFS with two different feature types and I am trying to work with BBox.

This KVP is working: http://inspire.maaamet.ee/arcgis/rest/services/public/au/MapServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=au:AdministrativeUnit&BBOX=59.664,26.3415,58.6268,26.3677,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258&COUNT=10 for the feature type called `au:AdministrativeUnit`.

But this one does not work:http://inspire.maaamet.ee/arcgis/rest/services/public/au/MapServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=mu:MaritimeBoundary&BBOX=59.664,26.3415,58.6268,26.3677,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258 for the feature type called `mu:MaritimeBoundary`

Why this is happening when I change only the feature type name? Could it be a problem from the server itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a look at the whole data of the mu:MaritimeBoundary feature type and BBOX gives a hint. The red geometry is your BBOX and green line is the maritime boundary.

[image]

The WfS server does not return data because your BBOX does not intersect with any feature. This request with a BBOX the goes further to the North returns data.

http://inspire.maaamet.ee/arcgis/rest/services/public/au/MapServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=mu:MaritimeBoundary&BBOX=60.664,26.3415,58.6268,26.3677,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258

Some servers (for example GeoServer) do the comparison with BBOX filter through a faster path, by comparing if the envelopes of the features intersect with the BBOX. However, the OGC Filter Encoding standard defines is so that ther should be real intersections:

```
> The <BBOX> element is defined as a convenient and more compact way of
> encoding the very common bounding box constraint based on the
> gml:Envelope geometry. It is equivalent to the spatial operation
> <Not><Disjoint> … </Disjoint></Not> meaning that the <BBOX> operator
> should identify all geometries that spatially interact with the box.
```

BTW. Your BBOX is wrong because the first coordinate pair should have the minimum values and the second one the maximum values. `59.664,26.3415,58.6268,26.3677` should be `58.6268,26.3415,59.664,26.3677`

Comment: Thanks for the comments about the BBOX, sorry for bothering with my mistake. With which software did you visualize this feature type and the BBox?

Comment: OpenJUMP http://openjump.org/.

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature inside your bounding box:

http://inspire.maaamet.ee/arcgis/services/public/au/MapServer/WMSServer?

[image]

Comment: Gosh... thanks. Which software did you use for the vizualisation?

Comment: Arcmap in layout view with a grid

Comment: Actually, even when I change the BBox, it does not filter: http://inspire.maaamet.ee/arcgis/rest/services/public/au/MapServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=mu:MaritimeBoundary&BBOX=58.383481,23.371564,59.540447,26.699738,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258&COUNT=1 with &BBOX=58.383481,23.371564,59.540447,26.699738