# Adding spatial filter to WFS layer request not working

Tags: qgis, wfs, filter, getfeature

I'm trying to load big WFS layers to my project by mean of a Python script but since I only need to display features located in the south west of France I thought I could easily add a bbox filter in the request url like this:

```
https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST:arrondissement&COUNT=1000&SRSNAME=EPSG::4326&BBOX=42.374778,-2.109375,47.115000,2.856445&request=GetFeature&
```

However, despite the bbox filter, the WFS layer is loaded nationwide every time I add it to the QGIS project.

How should I proceed to load only the features I want ?

I already had a look there:

- https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html
- https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8853
- [problem with Bounding Box GetFeature WFS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280790/problem-with-bounding-box-getfeature-wfs)
- https://www.linz.govt.nz/data/linz-data-service/guides-and-documentation/wfs-filter-methods-and-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SQL Query Composer` in the `WFS Server Connection Dialog` when adding the data. There you can create a spatial filter.
[image]

**EDIT:**
For using WFS via GeoServer in python and setting a bounding-box GeoServer requires a `POST` rather than a `GET` request as statet here:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html

*"While there are limited options available in a GET request for spatial queries (more are available in POST requests using filters), filtering by bounding box (BBOX) is supported."*

So one approach would be to query the data in your script beforehand making a post request and from the result create the layer on the fly:

That's how your query would look like in `curl`:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST:arrondissement&COUNT=1000&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&BBOX=47.0,2.7,47.1,2.8&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=json'
```

In QGIS you could load the data using `urllib` like:

```
from urllib import request, parse
import json

# Query Data
url = 'https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST:arrondissement&COUNT=1000&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&BBOX=47.0,2.7,47.1,2.8&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=json'
req = request.Request(url, method="POST")
r = request.urlopen(req)
content = r.read().decode('utf-8')
print(content)

# Add Layer
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(content,"Some Data","ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Note:
I changed your initial bounding box in the sample to a smaller value - your initial bounding box result has around 8MB of data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @bloigge but unfortunately I'm looking for an automated way to do that since my goal is to add this function within a qgis plugin

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: Awesome, thank you @bloigge !

Comment: Btw.: I just re-read the Geo-Server manual - you can use a GET Request as well in the python code ```req = request.Request(url)```

Comment: There is one downside: the use of ogr which makes the loading of layers far slower than with WFS. That's weird that we can't add a spatial filter with a WFS provider instead of ogr ! Do you know why ?

Comment: If you enable the debugging / development tools you can see that QGIS automatically appends a BBOX to every WFS request based on the current view (if it changes because of panning the map). So appending a BBOX to the URL of the WFS wouldn't work because QGIS overrules this every time you move the map. A solution would be to change the BBOX / query on the server - if you are not responsible use a proxy in between like mapproxy.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !