# SQL Query to limit loaded feature from WFS Layer to the extent of a feature in another layer

Tags: qgis, sql, wfs, filter, getfeature

I am trying to download all the features from a WFS layer (Land_Parcel_Layer) and save them locally.  The layer contains the land parcels for the whole federal state in Germany. The service URL is: https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_vereinfacht and I need the "ave:Flurstueck" feature type.

Since the data is huge I got the error for timeout for network request. I then increased in the options the related Timeout value, but this is not really helping since it still taking ages to load the features.

So the solution I thought is to limit the loaded features of "Land_Parcel_Layer" to the extent of an element in another layer, the "Region_Layer". I will then download the land parcel only from "Region A" inside the Layer "Region_Layer", then move to "Region B" and so on.
This is a basically a Selection by Location operation, which is very easy to do in ArcGis Pro and I guess also in QGIS.

I look at this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427910/adding-spatial-filter-to-wfs-layer-request-not-working) and I believe this is the right approach, but I have no knowledge in SQL and I am running out of time.

In the Build Query I would write something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Flurstueck
ST_Within(region_layer)
AND $region_name IS Koeln
```

but of course the syntax is all wrong, and from the Data selector on the right I can only select features from the WFS layer.

Comment: At the very least, you need a `WHERE` between `Flurstueck` and `ST_Within(region_layer)`

Comment: Which property name/element holds the information you want to filter on from: https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_vereinfacht?service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&typename=ave:Flurstueck&version=2.0.0&

Comment: Actually none of them. I though to use another layer to filter the WFS layer. But even if I want to use the element name="regbezirk", how can I use this if I dont know the different values inside regbezirk? I mean If I dont know that there is a regbezirk with value Colone, how am I supposed to write in the Build Query  
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE regbezirk = ´Colone´ 

??

Comment: Assuming you don't have a gazetteer, page through using `startindex` and `count` the 9349407 results of `https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_vereinfacht?service=WFS&request=GetPropertyValue&typenames=ave:Flurstueck&version=2.0.0&VALUEREFERENCE=regbezirk&`

Comment: Hi @nmtoken, would you mind to describe your method ina detailed way? Otherwise I cannot follow you. 
So I copy paste the XML link, and then I can see the field regbezirk for all 500000 features (i think this is the maximal numbers of features that can be visualized). How and where should I use the startindex and count functions?

Comment: To work out the number of results add `resulttype=hits&` to the request.  To fetch the second 500000 results add (instead) `startindex=500001&count=500000&` to the request.  To find out more about the OGC WFS specification try http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html

Comment: If I type "https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_vereinfacht?service=WFS&request=GetPropertyValue&typenames=ave:Flurstueck&version=2.0.0&VALUEREFERENCE=regbezirk&resulttype=hits&" what i get is an error message "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. "

Unfortunately I dont know XML and Its not practicable for me to learn it now from the doc.

Again what I need is a list of RegBezirk present in the dataset (around 40). They should be displayed only one time an not for each of the 100000 values.